# Java thread safe locking

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, synchronized

I am modifying a Java server software. The whole application is single threaded. One of my changes takes much time, so I have decided doing it asynchronously to avoid freezing the main-thread.

This is an example of the original code (not the real code, just an example):

```
public class Packet {
    private final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(int index, byte data) {
        this.data[index] = data;
    }

    public byte getData(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
    }
}
```

Currently this is my code (look at the comments):

```
public class Packet {
    private final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(int index, byte data) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.data[index] = data;
        }
    }

    public byte getData(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(final ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        //This state of data should be sent
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //The thread is now running
                //The main-thread can move on
                //The main-thread can also modify data now because we are not inside the synchronized block
                //But it should not because the state of data when the method sendPacket was called should be sent
                synchronized (Packet.this) {
                    thisTakesMuchTime(data);
                    clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

What I am actually looking for is something like that:

```
public class Packet {
    private final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(int index, byte data) {
        //wait for unlock
        this.data[index] = data;
    }

    public byte getData(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(final ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        //lock
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                thisTakesMuchTime(data);
                clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
                //unlock
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The question: What is the best implementation of such a lock in Java? Should I do it myself with an `AtomicInteger` for example.

Edit: Look at my answer for my current implementation.

Comment: it's not very clear what you're asking here.  what is the order of operations? do i first call `Packet.setData` and then `Packet.sendPacket`?  what do you want to do when the packet was sent?

Comment: In general I would avoid implementing your own locking code: never re-invent the wheel unless you absolutely have to. And there are things like ReentrantLock ... stuff that is well-document; and used by many other folks. Doing things "yourself" always carries the risk of getting it wrong.

Comment: Your locking ensures that you cannot write to a packet while it is being sent and you cannot send it while you are writing to it (from different threads). That doesn't seem like the best option. You should implement a pool for the `clientConnection`s so many packets can be transferred at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of your data, and send the copy, to avoid concurrency.

```
public class Packet {
    private final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(final int index, final byte data) {
        this.data[index] = data;
    }

    public byte getData(final int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(final ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        byte[] dataToSend = new byte[1024];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataToSend, 0, 1024);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                clientConnection.sendPacket(dataToSend);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is analogous to the code bellow, which also avoids concurrency but is not as efficient (given you'll be calling `setData` more often than `sendPacket`):

```
public class Packet {
    private byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(final int index, final byte data) {
        byte[] newData = new byte[1024];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, 1024);
        newData[index] = data;
        this.data = newData;
    }

    public byte getData(final int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(final ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I want to avoid making a copy on the main-thread.

Comment: @AntonK., what do you mean? "The whole application is single threaded."

Answer (score 1):

The simplest lock you can use is the [Reentrant Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), reentrant meaning that, if you attempt to acquire the lock when you already have it, the operation will succeed.

In your code, to achieve the threading you desire, you will also have to use `wait()` and `notify()` to block the main thread until your child thread has acquired the lock:

```
public class Packet {
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(int index, byte data) {
        lock.lock(); //wait for unlock
        try {
            this.data[index] = data;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public byte getData(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(final ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lock.lock(); //lock
                try {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        this.notify();
                    }

                    thisTakesMuchTime(data);
                    clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
                } finally { 
                    lock.unlock(); //unlock
                }
            }
        }).start();

        synchronized(thread) {
            try {
                thread.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //handle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider using an ExecutorService and not creating raw Thread objects.

Comment: I think you have missed the lock inside `setData`, right? But it is not functionally identical.

Comment: There was some copy-paste issues going on, I've since updated.

Comment: Okay, but the the first code is still not functionally identical with the second code. In the second code the main-thread is still able to call `setData` after calling `sendPacket` and before the packet is sent, which is actually my problem. The first code would solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think they're functionally different. What do you think synchronized is or isn't doing that the lock is or isn't doing (apart from creating the possibility of deadlock)?

Comment: In the first code it is locked on the main-thread, in the second code it is locked inside the started thread. Problem with the second code: main-thread calls sendPacket, sendPacket starts thread, thread is interrupted, main-thread moves on and calls setData, thread moves on and locks (with synchronized). As you can see the main-thread can call setData after calling sendPacket before reaching the synchronized block. (Maybe it's very unlikely but possible)

Comment: Ah, I see your conundrum, you want to acquire the lock before spinning off the thread. I shall make amendments.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best implementation of such a lock in Java? Should I do it myself with an AtomicInteger for example.

I think @ericbn's answer would work ok.  Grabbing a copy of the data using the main thread but still inside of  `Packet` is fine.

However you are worried about the 1k buffer?  The *real* expense here is not creating a copy of the data in the main thread, it's forking the thread *each time* you go to send the packet.  This is tremendously expensive compared to object creation.  I'd use a thread-pool and submit packet jobs to it.

```
// you might want this to be bounded so you don't queue up too many packets
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
...

public void sendPacket(ClientConnection clientConnection) {
    byte[] dataToWrite = new byte[data.length];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataToWrite, 0, dataToWrite.length);
    threadPool.submit(new PacketToWrite(dataToWrite, clientConnection));
    // you can clear or reset the `data` array now
}

private static class PacketToWrite implements Runnable {
    private final byte[] dataToWrite;
    private final ClientConnection clientConnection;
    public PacketToWrite(byte[] dataToWrite, ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        this.dataToWrite = dataToWrite;
        this.clientConnection = clientConnection;
    }
    public void run() {
        thisTakesMuchTime(data);
        clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
    }
}
```

You are sending data over the network so the extra object bandwidth is nothing compared to the network lag.

Comment: It would work with a copy of the data array. But the real data array is much larger and the packet is sent very often. So I really want to avoid copying the array. I already have a solution now with an own lock implementation. I know that would freeze my main thread, but only in rare cases (`setData` is called rarely).

Comment: I have just posted my current implementation as answer.

Answer (score 0):

My current implementation:

Packet:

```
public class Packet {
    private final Lock lock = new Lock();
    private final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    public void setData(int index, byte data) {
        lock.waitUntilUnlock();
        this.data[index] = data;
    }

    public byte getData(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    public void sendPacket(final ClientConnection clientConnection) {
        lock.lock();
        new Thread(new Runnable() { // I use an ExecutorService
            @Override
                public void run() {
                thisTakesMuchTime(data);
                clientConnection.sendPacket(data);
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Lock:

```
public class Lock {
    private final AtomicInteger lockCount = new AtomicInteger();

    public void lock() { // Main thread
        lockCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public synchronized void unlock() {
        lockCount.decrementAndGet();
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void waitUntilUnlock() { // Main thread
        try {
            while (lockCount.get() > 0) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```